# neuro network adaptive learning code

Tags: java, double, neural-network, nan

I have the following code

```
public void alearningrate(){

        //adopt learningrate 
        System.out.println(errorpositive+""+learningrate);
        if ((errorpositive&&errorgradient>0)||!errorpositive&&errorgradient<0){
            learningrate=learningrate*1.5;

        }else{
            learningrate=learningrate*0.75;
        }
        if (learningrate<0.0001){
            learningrate=0.0001;
        }
    }

    public void lastblame(double blame){

        errorpositive=errorgradient>0;
        errorgradient= Math.exp(-value)/Math.pow(1+Math.exp(-value), 2)*blame;
        if (value==Double.NaN){
            System.out.println("nan detected=?");
            errorgradient=1;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<weight.length;i++){
            weight[i]=weight[i]+learningrate*source[i].output()*errorgradient;
        }

        //alearningrate();

    }
    public void hiddenblame(double blame){
        System.out.println(value);
        errorpositive=errorgradient>0;
        errorgradient=Math.exp(-value)/Math.pow(1+Math.exp(-value), 2)*blame;
        if (value==Double.NaN){
            System.out.println("nan detected=?");
            errorgradient=1;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<weight.length;i++){
            weight[i]=weight[i]+learningrate*source[i].output()*errorgradient;
        }
        System.out.println(errorgradient);
        alearningrate();

    }
```

however this causus the errorgradient to quickly become NaN, but if I decide to remove the alearningrate() then the code runs fine. I looked at my functions errorgradient function and it should never yield nan, anybody know why I keep getting NaN?

Comment: For starters, value==Double.NaN will never be true since two NaNs are defined to compare false

Comment: In principle I'm look at a way to avoid NaN's but how would I detect them?

Comment: `Double#isNan(value)`

Comment: Plus, where's the error you're asking about? You don't have an `errorgradient` method, you have a *variable* named `errorgradient` that you're using in multiple places.

Comment: errorgradient becomes NaN so one of the methods is causing the errorgradient to become NaN. When I disable the alearngrate() methode it stops giving problems.